# Securing Spring boot rest Api with basic and Bearer Auth At the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use both basic auth and bearer Token to authenticate the same Api using Spring boot.

Each one works fine until. I add the other. Does any one had the same problem before ?

Comment: You have to show your Spring Security configuration. you could have multiple authentication types for one endpoint, but you can't authenticate with two types at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same endpoint cannot have both because the `Authorization` header needs to be either:

```
Basic ksjskjskjskjksj
```

or

```
Bearer djhkdjhdkjhdkhdkjh.ldjldkjldkjl.ldkjldkjldkj==
```

You need to intercept the outgoing call and *conditionally* add one or the other header.